# Android GCM importing package error

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm following a tutorial about the GCM on - [Android GCM Tutorial](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-tutorial/)

and I'm getting error when I put the these import statement
[image: import error]

even though the GCM library is installed in my SDK manager
[image: SDK manager]

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: the library should be in your libs fodler/in your class path

Comment: Specifically: copy yourSDKlocation\extras\google\gcm\gcm-client\dist\gcm.jar into your libs folder

Comment: Alright sir @NickT! Thanks. Why you only comment the answer? thats the best answer for my problem haha.

Answer (score 1):

Installing GCM gives you the library files. You also need to add the .jar file to build path in order to use it. Also, GCM is now Deprecated, consider using Google Play Services instead.

Comment: I also installed Google Play Service package. Does the process the same with that package? Should I also add some .jar file somewhere?

Comment: You should do either one. If its the google play service, you have to add as android library project.